# “Method not found: 'System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Builders.TableBuilder'"

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework

Currently i have a problem with Entity Framework.

When i run my website i receive the following error in the migration part of my project:

> Method not found: 'System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Builders.TableBuilder'

I have tried the fix here on StackOverflow, uninstalling and reinstalling EF. But without any success.

The weird part is that the problem exist with other developers in my team. There has been no commit just before the problems happens.

The only thing we did was trying to add a migration to EF. We also restored our database we try to connect to.

We also tried to restore,the backup from the server, the same DB local. If we connect to the local database everything works as expected.

I have no clue anymore and i hope someone can get me back on track.

**More handy info:**
2 solutions. One service that is referenced and has the database model and EF 5.0
the other solution is the website and had EF 6.0

The setup worked fine before.

Comment: Sounds like you have identified the issue. Why are you using 2 different versions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Steve Greene mentioned, it was because of 2 different versions.this probably started it all.

It looks like the DB is corrupted. Creating a new one works. Also restoring the DB on a new machine works.